# Why am I not able to import data using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a very beginner in python, I started learning only a few weeks ago.
I am working on jupyter notebook and try to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
health_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=0, sep=",")
print(health_data)
```

however I get a very long error message, ending with: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'`

I have tried to read some explanations of this common issue here on stackoverflow but still cannot get my way around it.

Comment: You haven't given the correct file path to `data.csv`

Comment: For more clarity, please show some first lines of your `data.csv`. Also you need to ensure the csv file is located in the same directory with the python file

Comment: Basically, it says you're not having such a file. This problem might occur if you've not specified the file path correctly.

Comment: @DhanaD. the lines of the CSV are irrelevant.

Comment: You're asking `jupyter` to find a file called `data.csv` _somewhere_ on your system. It isn't going to do that. You need to tell it in which directory the file is located

Comment: I don't know why is it irrelevant tbh? @roganjosh

Comment: Because it can't even find the file so what difference does the first few rows of the CSV make @DhanaD. ?

Comment: @DhanaD. the contents of the file don't affect the location

Comment: You can try to type `ls` to view all files and and `pwd` to see current directory in notebook

Comment: `ls` is a terminal command that's not valid in Python, so it won't run in Jupyter. I don't know what's going on with all these suggestions being thrown about - do the people commenting actually know how to read CSV files in `pandas`? It's becoming a confusing mishmash

Comment: `ls` and `pwd` will work in jupyter notebook. Jupyter notebook capable of terminal commands

Comment: For starters, give an absolute path to the file e.g. `"C:/example/cwd/mydir/data.csv"`. That will fix the issue. If `pwd` will work in Jupyter (I've stopped using it, so maybe I'm wrong in my last assertion) then you will be able to find the relative path rather than an absolute path

Comment: You can try to `import os` and run `os.listdir(os.curdir)` to view all file in the directory and view current directory try `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that 'data.csv' is in the same directory where you have the current .ipynb file?

Comment: It's not going to be a `py` file because it's a notebook for a start. This is a comment at best